# Turkey eVisa possible for residents for Australia?

Tags: turkey, pakistani-citizens, e-visas, australian-residents

If I am a permanent resident of Australia (with Pakistani Passport), can I get an eVisa to travel to Turkey for a week? Or do I have to go to Turkish Consulate physically to apply for it?

Comment: You apply online, pay a fee, and schedule an appointment. On your visit, submit the same papers you scanned and uploaded. Visa will be stamped on spot.

Comment: Can you tell me what URL to use to apply online? Is this one: https://www.evisa.gov.tr/ It doesn't ask for any papers. Can you please tell me what sort of papers are required? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can find the answer to your question on the [visa information page](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa) from the Turkish Ministry of Foreign Affairs.

As a Pakistani citizen, you can get a one month single entry eVisa if they already have a visa or residence permit from one of the Schengen countries, USA, UK or Ireland. Otherwise, you have to apply for a visa at a Turkish consulate.

Answer (score 1):

As a Pakistani not holding a valid Schengen, US, UK or Ireland visa or permanent residency; you need to apply for a visa before you travel.

The application process is online, including uploading of documents.  The documents required are typical for any visa process:

1. Current passport copy (in your case, you would also include the page that shows your visa (if applicable) to stay in Australia).
2. Any other document (such as an identity card) that shows your current non-immigrant status and the validity of it.
3. Your travel tickets.
4. Your hotel booking.
5. Proof of funds or support; normally this is a bank statement along with a salary letter from your employer.

The form asks you for other details about your trip; you also have to upload a passport sized photo.

Start the process at https://www.konsolosluk.gov.tr/Visa

Once you fill in the page and pay the fee, you'll be asked to reserve an appointment at the nearest embassy or mission.

You need to bring a copy of all your documents that you uploaded, along with your passport at your appointment.

Typically they will stamp the visa the same day; and it is usually for a single entry - especially if this is your first time applying.